# How to update onclick value when keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to update the function parameter inside `onclick` when the user inserts a quantity in the input field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="quantity1" class="quantity_class" />
<input type="submit" id="onclick1" class="quantity_class" value="Add to cart" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#quantity1').keyup(function () {
    $('#onclick1').attr('onclick', 'func(1,?)');
});
```

Now how can I replace `?` with the quantity value the user provided?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/UA5By/5/)

Comment: Why not just use proper event handlers for everything ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because whatever it is, this is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: im sorry im still new with jquery.. i try to update onclick paremeter with id and quantity.. this function is from opencart.

Comment: don't use `onclick` with jQuery. Don't ever set `onclick` to a string from code - that's basically `eval`. Don't forget you can access the DOM - and every variable in any outer scope - from a click handler. Don't modify the function call arguments dynamically by swapping functions if you can pass a reference instead (such as the input element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to update the inline onclick function on each keyup, just bind a click function to the button instead, and check the value of the quantity input on click :

```
$('#onclick').on('click', function() {
    func( 1, $('#quantity1').val() );
});
```

**EDIT:**

to remove the inline event handler if it can't just be removed in the markup :

```
$('#onclick').removeAttr('onclick').on('click', function() {
    func( 1, $('#quantity1').val() );
});
```

Comment: You can also use `.off` to remove handlers that were already bound to the element with `.on` before if you'd like.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum there's only one handler here. What's there to remove? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak - I'm guessing maybe he was thinking of the inline onclick handler, but that can't be removed with off().

Comment: He might also need to actually do `$("#onclick")[0].onclick=undefined` if that handler was not added with jQuery. (off would work if it was). OP's original code _replaced_ an event handler while this one adds one. I like this answer, I was just saying that in case this does not fully solve OP's issue, it can.

Comment: How do you add an inline event handler with jQuery, other than setting it as an attribute, and how would you remove that with off() ??? `off()` **only** removes events set with `on()`

Comment: @adeneo you shoudn't, but if you really want to, that would be `prop("onclick", ...)`.  Of course, `off` won't remove them..